# Make the span element inside div clickable

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list using javascript. Inside my div I have a span element with the text for the div, because I want to show/hide the text according to the screen size. As I added the span element the span area is not clickable. Other parts in that div are clickable and show the menu, except for the area with the span. How to make the span clickable as well?

Here's my code:

```
<div onclick="dropDownFunction()" class="dropbtn"><span>My List &nbsp;</span> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

And my codepen: http://codepen.io/nfds89/pen/MyLGKR

Comment: I don't see why you need the `window.onclick` at all - just remove it and your dropdown will work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxmdGW

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate CSS-only solution is to pass through clicks on the `<span>` and `<i>`

```
.dropbtn span,
.dropbtn i {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the below line in your code:

```
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
```

with the line below:

```
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn, .dropbtn span, .dropbtn i')) {
```

I just added `, .dropbtn span, .dropbtn i`.